# layout-land, black screen and force quit

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an app from the book "Hello Android". I've added a landscape view and it was working fine last night when I was testing. I got up this morning and it no longer works. I get a black screen and a force quit.

I've not changed nothing on the application. I'm using a Galaxy S2 to test with.

Here is my layout-land.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="30dip"
android:background="@color/background"
>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView  
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
android:textSize="24.5sp"
android:text="@string/main_title"
/>
<Button 
android:id="@+id/continue_button"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/continue_label"
/>
<Button 
android:id="@+id/new_button"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/new_game_label"
/>
 <Button
android:id="@+id/about_button"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/about_label"
/>
 <Button
android:id="@+id/exit_button"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/exit_label"
/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you paste the logcat trace?

Comment: Yeah sure, how do I get the logcat trace? Sorry I'm new to eclipse.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-projects.html

Answer (score 0):

When quitting Eclipse last night were you prompted to save all unsaved files? You may have saved an unsaved change you made earlier, either by accident or design, that is now being compiled into your project where it wasn't before? Start from the error message in Logcat and work back.